# RxJava - add new Observable at top of the chain

Tags: rx-java

Is it possible to add new `Observable` on top of the `Observable` **chain** already merged? or
Whenever I create new `Observable`, I have to build a new `Observable`?

Assume that I have a merged `Observable` like

```
val trackable1: PublishSubject[JSONObject] = PublishSubject.create()
val flushable: PublishSubject[JSONObject] = PublishSubject.create()
val merged = flushable
              .mergedWith(trackable)
              .map(json -> {
                if (storage.size > 50)
                // send HTTP request
              });

val trackable2: PublishSubject[JSONObject] = PublishSubject.create()

// I would like to add trackable2 as the event source like trackable1
// without rebuilding the `merged` Observable.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I solved by myself. Unsubscribing `Subscription` returned from `merged.subscribe` will stop `merged` observable including middle chains like `map`.

Comment: Just use `mergeWith` again: `merged.mergeWith(trackable2)` then subscribe to this new sequence.